# ES6 import of electron modules with Vite/Vue fails

Tags: javascript, electron, vite

I am trying to use electron with latest Vite 2/Vue 3. I have setup two versions of electron's main file so I can test and work with both dev server and the build:

- dev version loading the localhost:3000 (from *npm run dev*) with loadURL
- another version loading the built version (from *npm run build*)from the *dist* folder with loadFile

I have set in the new BrowserWindow options:

```
webPreferences: {
   nodeIntegration: true,
   contextIsolation: false,
   enableRemoteModule: true,
   preload: path.join(app.getAppPath(), 'electron.preload.js')
}
```

The app starts just fine in Electron in both dev and build version, loads all assets and without any security errors. However, when I try to import any module from 'electron' in my project, in example:

```
import electron from 'electron';
```

I get the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: path.join is not a function
    at node_modules/electron/index.js (index.js:4)
```

I tried to check *path* and *__dirname*, to see if they work in my project:

```
import * as path from 'path';

console.log(path);
console.log(path.join);
console.log(__dirname);
```

And these do trace out the following in Electron dev panel:

[image]

If I try to import *path* differntly:

```
import path from 'path'
console.log(path);
console.log(path.join);
```

I get the following result:

[image]

In any case, *path.join* is undefined. And now I am pretty much stuck on how to go on.

I can also add that I want to use fs-extra, but this also fails:

```
import fs from 'fs-extra';
```

[image]

[Edit: added the preload in webPreferences]

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this error? I have a similar problem.

Comment: Not really, using require() to make it work e.g. >> const { app } = require('@electron/remote');

Answer (score 1):

I believe Vite transforms things a lot behind the scenes. Thankfully `@electron/remote` provides an alternate way to fetch things:

`electron.js`:

```js
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require("electron");
const Remote = require("@electron/remote/main");

Remote.initialize();

// ...

app.on("ready", () => {
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true,
      enableRemoteModule: true,
      contextIsolation: false,
    },
  });

  Remote.enable(mainWindow.webContents);

  mainWindow.loadFile(path.resolve("./dist", "index.html"));
});

// ...
```

`Component.tsx`:

```
import type { BrowserWindow } from "electron";


const Component: React.FC = () => {
  const app = window.require("@electron/remote");
  const win: BrowserWindow = app.getCurrentWindow();

  // ...
}
```

Not sure if this is the best solution, but it works for me with Vite + Electron + React.

Answer (score 0):

In my case preload resolved the issue

```
import { contextBridge, nativeImage } from 'electron';

if (process.contextIsolated) {
  try {
    contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('nativeImage', nativeImage);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
} else {
  window.nativeImage = nativeImage;
}
```

And then in vue side just use

`window.nativeImage`